# How to create fixed length multi dimensional array in php?

Tags: php

`int twodim[5][8];
int threedim[3][5][8];`

How to create fixed length multi dimensional array in php as we create in c++ ?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask.

Comment: PHP arrays are dynamic, you don't need to declare them and there is no fixed size.

Comment: Note that php as a non declarative programming language does not use strict types. It follows a much more dynamic approach, arrays and objects can be modified no only in values but also in structure "on the fly".

Comment: Dear , I just want to create fixed length multi dimensional array in php as we create in c++ ?

Answer (score 2):

To create fixed array you should use [SplFixedArray](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) from [Standard PHP Library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) extension:

> The SplFixedArray class provides the main functionalities of array. The main differences between a SplFixedArray and a normal PHP array is that the SplFixedArray is of fixed length and allows only integers within the range as indexes. The advantage is that it allows a faster array implementation.

Comment: Dear we cannot create multi dimensional array using SplFixedArray.

Comment: What is preventing you from nesting the SplFixedArray to create a multi dimensinal array?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very PHP-like, but you can use this function (based on Grzegorz' [`SplFixedArray`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) hint) to generate fixed sized arrays of any dimension.

```
function createFixedArray() {
  $args = func_get_arg(0);
  $array = new SplFixedArray($args[0]);

  if (isset($args[1])) {
    $newArgs = array_splice($args, 1);
    for ($i=0; $i<$args[0]; $i++) {
      $array[$i] = createFixedArray($newArgs);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Example use:

```
$fixedArray = createFixedArray(array(2, 2, 2));

$fixedArray[0][0][0] = 0;
$fixedArray[0][0][1] = 1;

$fixedArray[0][1][0] = 1;
$fixedArray[0][1][1] = 0;

$fixedArray[1][0][0] = 1;
$fixedArray[1][0][1] = 0;

$fixedArray[1][1][0] = 0;
$fixedArray[1][1][1] = 1;

var_dump($fixedArray);
```

Generates

```
object(SplFixedArray)#1 (2) {
  [0]=>
  object(SplFixedArray)#2 (2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SplFixedArray)#3 (2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SplFixedArray)#4 (2) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SplFixedArray)#5 (2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SplFixedArray)#6 (2) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SplFixedArray)#7 (2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As i know that creating arrays at runtime takes much time, becase every time we create arrays with new it will delete old memory occupied by array and then create new sized array at new memory location and also will copy and paste the array data. My code may generate  huge size arrays do u think this will be good idea to generate huge size arrays at runtime.... As i told i want to create fixed multi diem. array but not at runtime ...

Comment: Run some tests with your own data to see how it works processing and memory wise. Your data and setup aren't clear in the question and are outside of its scope a bit.